# Updating hash location does not jump to anchor in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, hash

Doing

```
window.location.hash = '#someanchor';
```

in javascript running on firefox 37.0 (Ubuntu 14.04) seems to do nothing. Well the hash appears in the URL bar but the page does not jump to it. In chrome the same script/html causes the page to jump to the anchor as I would expect. Is this a bug or something I'm missing?

Doing `location.reload()` does force firefox to jump, but I'd rather not have the expense of a refresh to just jump to an achor.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was that my anchor hand't loaded in time before the script ran (I assume Chrome must wait for it, but Firefox doesn't). Wrapping the script in `$(document).ready(function(){....});` was enough to fix things.